# Problemas en BackEnd con JavaScript al publicar imágenes y verlo en Postman

Tags: javascript, backend, postman

Muestra del mensaje de error definido por mi en Postman y el código

El problema está en que, al momento de cambiar el condicional if de posición (abajo del 'success'), me da el mensaje success, pero aunque el if esté arriba, la imágen se sigue guardando en la dirección en la que la he dejado.

PEEERO, cuando quiero obtener la imagen, me da error aunque ponga el nombre de la imágen con su extensión

```
if (articleId) {
            // Buscar el articulo, asignarle el nombre de la imagen y actualizarlo
            Article.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: articleId }, { image: file_name }, { new: true }, (err, articleUpdated) => {


                if (err || !articleUpdated) {
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: 'error',
                        message: 'Error al guardar la imagen de articulo!!!'
                    });
                }


                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    article: articleUpdated
                });
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                image: file_name
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hay una palabra en programación que me encanta. Se llama INDENTACIÓN, y sirve para que tu código sea mucho más legible (en python además define los bloques del código cual corchete invisible). Cuando compartas código, por favor utiliza una correcta indentación y no pongas bloques de código suelto... puesto que hace imposible seguir el flujo del mismo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, me ha sido de ayuda

Comment: @DiegoGuzmán puedes compartir el error que te ha dado?

Comment: Si existe la variable `articleId` intentas actualizar (`if articleId`), pero si no existe, ¿qué estás haciendo? Estás enviando un mensaje de `success` al Cliente. ¿Logras ver el problema?

Comment: Claro que existe la variable `articleId`